# Mapbox GL JS MarkerClusterGroup on Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, leaflet, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I am making an application in Ionic / Angular using the MapBox GL and Leaflet library. Anyway, I happen to have problems implementing the L.MarkerClusterGroup () function. Currently I use a function to load from firebase the data of each marker, this works fine but adds the layers to the map to add each marker to the MarkerClustergroup object.

Here is the function I use to instantiate the map

```
getCurrentCoordinates() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      this.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
      this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'mapBox',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/cherniakovsky/ckn3idmad27xu17r1fb13a6rx',
        center: [this.longitude, this.latitude],
        zoom: 16.15,
        maxZoom: 18,
        cluster: true,
        clusterMaxZoom: 14,
        clusterRadius: 50
        });
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error getting location', error);
     });
  }
```

This work fine and then I load the markers with the next function

```
  loadPins() {

    for (const rec of this.chatRooms) {
      const icons: Record<string, { icon: string }> = {
        rec: {
          icon: rec.img.filepath,
        },
      };
      let el = window.document.createElement('div');
      el.id = 'avatar';
      el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + rec.img.filepath + ')';
      el.style.width = '50px';
      el.style.height = '50px';
      el.style.borderRadius = '50%';
      el.style.backgroundSize = '50px';
      el.draggable = true;
      const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }).setHTML(this.definePopup(rec));
      const latlngM = L.latLng(rec.location.longitude, rec.location.latitude);
      this.marcadores =
      new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat({lon: rec.location.longitude, lat: rec.location.latitude }).setPopup(popup).on('popupopen', e => {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.chat-link')
        .addEventListener('click', () => this.openChat(rec));
      }).addTo(this.map);
      this.clusters.addLayer(L.marker(latlngM));
      this.map.addLayer(this.clusters);
    }
}
```

Finally the function load the markers but not clusters them. The variable this.clusters is instantaneous like this:

```
  clusters = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({

    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: '#3887be',
      color: '#3887be',
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.5
    }
  });
```

I look a lot in internet examples but when i try to add the layer to the map y recive a lot of error message with undefined layer. I don't understand why.
thanks for read

Comment: You're... mixing Leaflet layers with a MapboxGL map? And there's no errors in the browser's console?

Comment: The console trow this errors: 
Error: layers.undefined: either "type" or "ref" is required
Error: layers.undefined: missing required property "source"
Error: layers.undefined: missing required property "id"

Comment: These errors appears when i try the clustersMarkerGroup to the map by this way:       this.clusters.addTo(this.map);